# How do we pass the arguments for the relationship properties in neo4j.rb?

Tags: neo4j.rb

Neo4j.rb project. From the docs.

```
student = Student.first
lesson = Lesson.new
student.lessons << lesson
```

How do we pass the arguments for the relationship properties for the relationship between `student` and `lesson`?

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's not in the docs but in [screencasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veqIfIqtoNc&list=PL5klM3mD6alLUhNTPTbj5a3GBjU7oZN0t&index=3)

```
student.lessons.create(lesson, enrolment_date: "blah")
```